# react-router how to configure the index route using Javascript object?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've tried the following and it's not working:

```jsx
const routeConfig = [
            {
                // path: '/',
                component: MyApp,
                indexRoute: {component: Homepage},
                childRoutes: routes
            }
        ];
        React.render(<Router history={history} routes={routeConfig} />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

The "Homepage" component is ignored entirely!

I'm using react-router 1.0.0 and react 0.13.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all the best thing to do is to upgrade to the 1.0 final (there are no breaking changes - just bug fixes)

See the example below on how to use plain routes with `IndexRoute`:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
import { Router } from 'react-router'

const Home = () =>
  <h3>Home</h3>

const App = (props) =>
  <div>
    <h1>App</h1>
    <Navigation />
    {props.children}
  </div>

const routes = [
  {
      path: '/',
      component: App,
      indexRoute: {
        component: Home
      }
  }
]

const Root = () =>
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()} routes={routes} />


render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Edit:** I created an example for you [here](https://github.com/knowbody/react-router-playground/tree/master/plain-routes). When you clone the repo, navigate to `plain-routes` example and `npm install && npm start`.

Comment: I've updated my question - I'm already using react-router 1.0.0. If you also meant I should give the 'path' parameter and change my 'indexRoute" parameter, I did just now and it's not working still `Location "/" did not match any routes`

Comment: edited my question with the example, hope that helps

Comment: thank you for building an example for me, it's working as expected. However, you are using React 0.14.0 and react-dom. Also, your latest code snippet looks exactly like mine

Comment: The react version has nothing to do with it. You can change the example to use React 0.13. Yes it looks the same. By giving you minimal working example I'm trying to point out that something else must be done wrong in your code. It's hard to say what it is from the code you provided.